# Weil pairing of P and Q

Tags: pairings

it the following example for page 56 of the book http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/PairingsForBeginners.pdf I could not understand how the author found the Weil pairing of two points p and Q. I attached the picture of the example. Can you help me to this? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

They used Miller's algorithm, which is explained in the next chapter.

(To be concrete, they used a implementation in Magma which is available in the [author's website](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairing/))

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to work with Magma. I should to understand ABE and try to understand pairing for that. So, I do not know that if I would need to Magma or not? What is your idea?

Comment: @tesoke you don't need to know Magma to understand the book. But it certainly helps if you want a more concrete understanding. If you don't have access to Magma, you could rewrite the scripts in Sage - it would be a good exercise.